# Get all polygons that intersect with a circle around a given point

Tags: mysql, spatial

I am finding a lot on how to find all POINTS that are contained in a circle drawn around a location (using the Haversine formula) in MySQL.

My function should return all polygons that are at least partially intersecting with the circle.

1. How do I create that circle?
2. How do I check if a polygon intersects with that circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old, but it is still one of the topmost Google hits when searching for this issue. The existing answer is not useful as it cannot reasonably be implemented for use in MySQL - at least not in any manner that has remotely acceptable performance.

The solution is to use ST_Buffer with your point / radius:

```
ST_Buffer(point, radius)
```

An example query, for a table containing a column "polygon" which contains polygon data, to return rows that a circle with center at point mypoint with radius of 9 intersects:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ST_Intersects(polygon, ST_Buffer(mypoint, 9))
```

Answer (score 2):

You neglected to mention whether or not your working in 2D or 3D. Given that you said `circle` rather than `sphere`, i'll assume you mean 2D.

To find all polygons that intersect with a circle you will need to know:

a) The origin of each polygon (more specifically, the center of the polygon).

b) The origin of the circle.

c) The diameter (or radius) of the circle.

With these values, you can determine the distance between the center of the circle and the center of each polygon. If the magnitude of the distance between the center of the circle and the center of the polygon is less than the radius of the circle, the polygon intersects.

I'm not overly sure how you would plug this into an SQL query as you would first need to calculate the magnitudes of each polygon in relation to the circle and then evaluate them against the radius of the circle. It's been a while since i've written and SQL but I imagine it would be somewhere along the lines of the following:

- Gather all items where the distance between the center of the polygon and the center of the circle is greater than the radius.

See this handy image for further illustration:

[image: circle intersections]

This would only provide a very rough and basic way to determine intersections as this doesn't take into consideration complex shapes. Essentially, this is more along the lines of sphere vs sphere intersection where a bounding sphere would encompass your polygon. It may provide false positives in some situations but you could easily pass these results on to a more fine grained collision detection to filter down the results as needed.

Hope that helps!